# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

When I start my flutter app, Im getting this error:

```
   Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[19.0.
      2]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.
```

My dependencies in build gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.4.0'
    
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.10'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    }
    
    
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please help me) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent versioning conflicts between Firebase SDKs, I recommend using the [Firebase Bill of Materials (BoM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more#bom) to manage the versions.

With the BoM, you'd have the following dependencies for Firebase:

```
dependencies {
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')

  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
}
```

So as you can see, the only version we specify is for the Bill of Materials itself This in turn then specifies the (compatible) versions of the specific product SDKs.